# How to block a value in a global memory array in an OpenCL kernel?

Tags: synchronization, opencl, atomic

I've got a problem with synchronization between OpenCL work items. I have an array of unsigned shorts in the global memory of a device. Work items work with this array, and I have to make it so that when one of them works with a value in this array, no other work items should do something with it. But this has to be implemented only for individual values not for the entire array:

```c
__kernel void calculateValues(
    __global unsigned short* values)
{
    // some code before... getting i...
    // values[i] has been blocked, but values[i+1] and others haven't been blocked
    unsigned short current_value = values[i];
    // some work with current_value...
    values[i] += current_value;
    // values[i] has been unblocked
}
```

Possibly, it's related to atomic functions, but I never used them, thus a complete newbie here. How should this be done? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**: This's a much closer to my real work example of this kernel's code:

```c
__kernel void
setNodeStableConnectionWeight(
    volatile __global       ushort* node_signal_transmission_weights,
             __global const ushort* node_signal_transmission_weight_limit,
             __global const ushort* node_signal_transmission_noise_weight,
             __global const uint  * node_signal_receiver_ids)
{
    const uint
        node_id                                                        = get_global_id(0U);
    const ushort
        node_signal_transmission_sender_side_weight_limit              = node_signal_transmission_weight_limit[node_id];
    const ushort
        node_signal_transmission_noise_weight_local_copy               = *node_signal_transmission_noise_weight;
          uint
        node_signal_receiver_id                                        = node_signal_receiver_ids[node_id];
          ushort
        node_signal_transmission_receiver_side_weight;
           bool
        node_connection_correlation_exists                             = true;
    while (node_connection_correlation_exists) {

        // Block read and write of node_signal_transmission_weights[node_signal_receiver_id] for any other work items! Or wait if it's already blocked by another work item.
        node_signal_transmission_receiver_side_weight                  = node_signal_transmission_weights[node_signal_receiver_id];
        if (node_signal_transmission_sender_side_weight_limit          < node_signal_transmission_receiver_side_weight) {
            node_signal_transmission_receiver_side_weight             -= node_signal_transmission_sender_side_weight_limit;
            node_connection_correlation_exists                         = doesNodeConnectionCorrelationExist(
                node_signal_transmission_receiver_side_weight,
                node_signal_transmission_sender_side_weight_limit,
                2U);
            if (node_connection_correlation_exists) {
                if (node_signal_transmission_receiver_side_weight      < node_signal_transmission_noise_weight_local_copy)
                    node_signal_transmission_receiver_side_weight++;
                else if (node_signal_transmission_receiver_side_weight > node_signal_transmission_noise_weight_local_copy)
                    node_signal_transmission_receiver_side_weight--;
            }
            else
                node_connection_correlation_exists                     = true;
        }
        else
            node_signal_transmission_receiver_side_weight             += node_signal_transmission_noise_weight_local_copy;
        node_signal_transmission_weights[node_signal_receiver_id]      = node_signal_transmission_receiver_side_weight;

        // Unblock read and write of node_signal_transmission_weights[node_signal_receiver_id].
        node_signal_receiver_id                                        = node_signal_receiver_ids[node_signal_receiver_id];
        if (node_id                                                   == node_signal_receiver_id)
            node_connection_correlation_exists                         = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want some kind of locking, or atomic transactions to implement an arbitrary atomic-RMW.  (On a CPU, you could use a CAS retry loop to apply a change to an element as an atomic RMW.  I don't know if any of this is possible on a GPU.)

Answer (score 2):

OpenCL is not designed around blocking synchronisation inside kernels, due to the way GPUs typically work. I recommend you try to redesign your algorithm so it avoids blocking. This *does* likely require the use of atomic operations for all but embarrassingly parallel problems, but in order to get help here with that you will need to provide more detail about what problem you're ultimately trying to solve.

If you absolutely do have an unavoidable critical synchronisation point in your algorithm, you will need to split your kernel. Then, enqueue the second kernel in the same serial queue after the first kernel, or specify the completion event of your first kernel as a requirement for your second kernel's execution to commence.

Comment: Every work item works with one element (that is just a `ushort` value) from this array, but we can't know beforehand which exact element this is. Then, typically there are several work items that "choose" the same element to work with, in this case we have to avoid any situations when two or more work items work with one element at the same time, one can start working with it only after another one finishes this if there's a work item that is currently working with that element, because every "work" can change its value.

Comment: I can't tell you what work is there because there are lots of different functions.